# There was a conflict between "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, .net-assembly

Getting the below error from the build pipeline. It is complaining about the conflicts between "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0" and "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1". Still struggling to fix it. Tried different suggestions none worked. all the app.config files got the assembly binding too. Please advise.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

[image]

--- Updated ---------
[image]

Comment: Check your dependencies and check which one depends on `4.2.0.0`

Comment: Could you please provide your .csproj file?

Comment: Here are ( See the post edited to reflect the image ) the list of projects that NDepend tool shows me as having dependenct to 4.2.0.0 version . But when I check those projects they all have reference t0 4.2.0.1 !